# How to avoid getting cropped marginpar?

Tags: margins, marginpar, geometry, fixme

I'm using the `fixme` package to add notes to various parts of my thesis draft. However, if I set the margins using the `geometry` package, I notice that the fixme notes are not formatted correctly (with margin overflow). Is there a simple fix? MWE below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\usepackage[lmargin=1.3in,rmargin=1.3in,bottom=1.3in,top=1.3in,twoside=False]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\listoffixmes


stuff \fixme{Here is where I would put a really long fixme note, so long in fact that it might seem silly....}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have been using the `todonotes` package, and not familiar with `fixme`, but its not clear to me exactly what the problem is with the formatting of the output.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be any problem; the "fixme" notes, for which the command `\fxnote` should be used instead of the deprecated `\fixme`, are typeset with the width of the normal marginal notes, which is the parameter `\marginparwidth`; indeed, adding

```
marginparwidth=0.5in
```

to the options passed to **geometry** typesets the note in a very narrow column.

Answer (score 3):

### Case 1

You use `oneside` and the default `includemp` which is false. The marginpar will be on the right side margin. In this case, you must make sure

```
marginparsep + marginparwidth < rmargin
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft,letterpaper,oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{fixme}
\usepackage
[
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %
    %for symmetrical margin, just use margin instead of lmargin, rmagin, etc.
    margin=1.3in,
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %
    %includemp=true,% uncomment this if you want the marginpar is placed inside the outer margin.
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %
    %If you use oneside document and default includemp (which is false)
    %marginparwidth + marginparsep < rmargin
    marginparwidth=1in,
    marginparsep=0.2in
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
]{geometry}

\def\dummy{I can find a tool to convert EPS to PDF in my neither bathroom nor kitchen.}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\listoffixmes
\lipsum[1] 
\fixme{\dummy}
\lipsum[3]
\newpage
\lipsum[4] 
\fixme{\dummy}
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

### Case 2

You use `oneside` and `includemp=true`. The marginpar will be on the right side but it gets moved `rmargin` to the left. You must make sure that

```
marginparsep + marginparwidth < textwidth
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft,letterpaper,oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{fixme}
\usepackage
[
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %
    %for symmetrical margin, just use margin instead of lmargin, rmagin, etc.
    margin=1.3in,
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %
    includemp=true,%marginpar is placed inside the outer margin.
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %
    %If you use oneside document and includemp = true
    %marginparwidth + marginparsep < textwidth
    marginparwidth=1.9in,
    marginparsep=0.1in
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
]{geometry}

\def\dummy{I can find a tool to convert EPS to PDF in my neither bathroom nor kitchen.}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\listoffixmes
\lipsum[1] 
\fixme{\dummy}
\lipsum[3]
\newpage
\lipsum[4] 
\fixme{\dummy}
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a simplified answer in case it helps anybody, as it would have helped me:

There are two solutions. One is to add `ignoremp=false` to the options for `geometry`. This will cause the margins for the entire document to be expanded to fit the largest note - which is probably not desirable, unless you are planning to leave the fixme notes in place long term.

The other solution is to set `marginparwidth=` to a slightly smaller size than your right (or outer) margin. This sets the width that Fixme formats its notes to.

For example, this works for me:

```
\usepackage[
    top=2cm, bottom=3cm, inner=2cm, outer=3cm,
    marginparwidth=2cm %necessary to avoid breaking fixme notes.
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin]{fixme}
```