# How can I set up the left/right margin of the page to 1 inch, the top/bottom one to ½ inch?

Tags: margins, geometry

I try to set up the left and right margins to 1 inch, top and bottom margins to 0.5 inch. The following is my code:

```
% Setup the margin
\usepackage[centering, margin={1in, 0.5in}, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.6in} 
\setlength{\headsep}{25pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{25pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{11pt}
```

But I don't know why the result doesn't show me the correct page setup.

[image]

As you can see, obviously the bottom margin is 0 and the footer is missing. That's not what I set up. Could anybody tell me what's wrong with my code? and how to fix it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because you overrode the default settings  defined by the `geometry` package (such as `\footskip`) then the last settings will be applied to take effect. You set `\footskip` to `25pt` and that is too small!

I recommend that you use `geometry`'s settings only rather than mixing them with native length macros. The following native length macros should not be used if you have already loaded the `geometry` package.

```
\setlength{\headheight}{0.6in} 
\setlength{\headsep}{25pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{25pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{11pt}
```

The link [How to avoid getting cropped marginpar?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23673/how-to-avoid-getting-cropped-marginpar/23684#23684) and the following code snippet may help you to understand how to set up the page layout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=1cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=3cm,
        bottom=4cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

If you need more, drop a comment.