# Padding left, top, right and bottom in LaTeX

Tags: margins

I want to include the **Padding left, top, right and bottom**. How can we do in LaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to give more detail on where this 'padding' is located.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the geometry package could be used:

```
\usepackage[%
    left=0.50in,%
    right=0.50in,%
    top=1.0in,%
    bottom=1.0in,%
    paperheight=11in,%
    paperwidth=8.5in%
]{geometry}%
```

Also see xports answer to [How can I set up the left/right margin of the page to 1 inch, the top/bottom one to ½ inch?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23742/question-about-setting-up-the-margin-of-the-page)

Comment: Is this margin or padding. Then how to set for (margin - left right top bottom). I am asking for padding, what is the tag? Please reply margin tag and padding tag separately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is for page. In a table how to set padding.

Comment: Please see this link first: [How to add border and padding to contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20640/how-to-add-border-for-an-image/20642#20642) If you are satisfied with the given link, don't forget to up vote it. :-)

Comment: Please see Joseph's comment about providing a MWE.

Answer (score 6):

Note that LaTeX itself doesn't differ between margin and padding, because it actually doesn't now this concepts. They are normally not required for typesetting. Books are simply done differently than websites.

The `adjustbox` package includes a `\marginbox` which allows to add a margin (or padding) around a boxed content. There is also a `margin` option for `\adjustbox` or the `adjustbox` environment.

There are three different ways to define the margin/padding:

```
\marginbox{<all sites>}{<content>}
\marginbox{<left/right> <top/bottom>}{<content>}
\marginbox{<left> <bottom> <right> <top>}{<content>}
```

Or use `\adjustbox` or `{adjustbox}`:

```
\adjustbox{margin=...}{<content>}
\begin{adjustbox{margin=...}
    <content>
\end{adjustbox}
```

**If you want to set padding, draw a frame/border around it and then add some margin use:**

```
\begin{adjustbox{margin=<l> <b> <r> <t>,frame=<thickness>,margin=<l> <b> <r> <t>}
    <content>
\end{adjustbox}
```

Here the first `margin` sets the padding, the second the margin. If you only want equal padding on all four sides you can also use the optional separation (`<sep>`) argument of the `fbox` option:

```
\begin{adjustbox{fbox=<thickness> <sep>,margin=<l> <b> <r> <t>}
    <content>
\end{adjustbox}
```

Comment: What if I want to set padding around the page body (on all pages), draw a frame/border around it and then add some margin? The `geometry` package doesn't seem to have an option for this because it doesn't separate padding and margin. -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122683/3463