# How do you create spaces between Images?

Tags: spacing, graphics

How do you create spaces between Images? I have tried using the commands `//` after paragraphs that precede images but this only produces a space between the paragraph and the image. I have also used `//` between images but this caused the error: `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`

Just give me some commands to copy and paste to separate images. I have minimal knowledge of programming I just want to be able to separate the images.

Comment: You need vertical and horizontal spaces, don't you? You can add a margin around an image using the `adjustbox` package. See [Padding left, top, right and bottom in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28638), but you can also use the `margin=...` key with `\includegraphics` when loading `adjustbox` with the `export` option.

Comment: What in text command do I need to create said margin between images?

Answer (score 6):

You should avoid using `\\` at all inside a document other than ending table rows. An image has no special spacing in LaTeX it is just exactly like a big letter so you can space it the same way.

If you want to put one above the other, put them in separate paragraphs with a blank line between them. As for any paragraphs you can either set `\parskip` length to control the vertical space or just explicitly use `\vspace` to ass extra space.

To separate two images horizontally, again just as for separating two letters, use `\hspace`