# How can I remove the indent after every section in new page?

Tags: indentation

I am using a preconfigured LaTeX file and have a problem. After I use `\section{}`, everything works well, but only on the current page. If I reach the new page, I have an indent on the left side and the current section is written like a header.
How can I disable that?

I've already tried `\noindent`, `\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}`, `\setlength{\parskip}{4em}`, `\parindent`, `\parskip`... to no avail. What should I do?

EDIT:

```
\begin{document}

\include{TEXT}

TEXT looks like:
\chapter{TEXT}
this is my text....

after reaching new page i get the indent on the left side as mentioned above...
hope this helps

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is not clear. Can you show an example of how you're coding your text?

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would indeed be great, cause right now i can't even imagine what you are describing.

Comment: sorry I am really new to Latex so I try to explain it:
first i use 
\chapter{New chapter}
TEXT TEXT TEXT

If I reach a new page, the left side is indented...I have no plan how to remove this

Comment: This won't happen in the standard article class.  Presumably you're using the book or report class.  Either way, you can fix this using something like `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`

Comment: @JPi Probably a bad idea.

Comment: superb, worked, only now the subsection title is forced to the upper side

Comment: perhaps you are describing the "offset" of all the even pages with the `twoside` `\documentclass` option.  (this is to allow for punching holes to put in a ring-binder.)  if that is the case, insert `[oneside]` between `\documentclass` and the named class.

Comment: @Jubobs: why?  Nick: you can adjust each individual margin as you please.  See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23742/how-can-i-set-up-the-left-right-margin-of-the-page-to-1-inch-the-top-bottom-one

Comment: @Nick We're unlikely to get anywhere, unless you edit your question to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: question edited

Comment: @Nick: A single code line of a failingdocument is minimal, but not working ;-) So it is a by - far - non - MWE ;-)

Comment: A minimal working example looks something like `\documentclass{book}  \begin{document} ... \end{document}`

Comment: You can also follow the link i provided above.

Comment: If I would know where the problem is, I could change it...
Having a Latex-template and this problem occurs...I can't tell you where the problem is, hope you can tell me

@Johannes: thx, working on it =)

Comment: @Nick: And now tell us, what is inside the file `TEXT`, which you `\include` ...

Comment: Just show something short that's compilable that demonstrates the problem that you're having.

Comment: @Christian: is written in the question...
only /section{} following by a lot of text...

Comment: @Nick: I don't want to argue with you, but there is no direct connection from that `\section` line to the code ;-)

Comment: there is no more code!
the funny thing is, on page 3 the indent is on the right side...

Comment: Sorry @Johannes_B; had not noticed your post.

Comment: @Nick: what's the document class?

Comment: @JPi: documentclass: srcbook

Comment: Finally I fixed it by setting the laterality to false in the documentclass. Thank you guys!

Comment: One additional comment (also good for life): Don't panic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the original poster has answered it in the comments.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which option is that precisely?

Comment: Where the documentclass is defined, there is an option to select a oneside or twoside mode (for printing). By switching that off, the text is in the middle of every page